# Excel Custom format Check for character

Tags: excel, format

**What I need is** custom format to change values according to these rules:

1. If "/" is absent and number's length is less than 6, add zeroes to
   the begining.
2. If "/" is present and number's length before"/" is less than 6, add
   zeroes to the begining.
3. If "/" is present and number's length after "/" is 1, add zero
   before last character.
4. If "/" is present and number's length after "/" is 2, leave as it
   is.
5. Total length of string with "/" would be 8, without it - 6

**Unformatted data:**

```
-534  
1083  
386840/2  
12345/10
```

**Desired result:**

```
000534  
001083  
38684002  
01234510
```

**What I came up so far:**
000000;000000;0 is pretty obvious part, value without "/" will be read as number anyway. If it was a number, I would use `[>1000]0` or something like that but it doesn't work with `Text` as far as I understood.
*Formula I'm using (just for now) instead of desirable custom format:*

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("/";A1));  
    CONCATENATE(REPT("0";6-LEN(A1));A1);  
    IF((LEN(A1)-FIND("/";A1))=1;  
        SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(REPT("0";7-FIND("/";A1));A1);"/";"0");  
        SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(REPT("0";7-FIND("/";A1));A1);"/";"")))
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You can't ask the number format to inspect your number. Therefore you must convert 40/2 into 4002 and 5/10 into 510 before you submit it to the NumberFormat. You ought to be able to do that with a helper column (which you might keep hidden), but if that isn't possible than your only recourse would be VBA.

Comment: @Variatus Can't do, that was the reason for number format in the first place, otherwise I would use formulas.

Comment: You have to tell more. Are you allowed to change the data in the column where they are? Just forget to do it with NumberFormat. Must find another solution.

Comment: Number Formats in Excel only affect numbers.  They cannot be used to change how text is represented.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld This https://www.cheatography.com/nqramjets/cheat-sheets/excel-cell-number-formatting/ might not me reliable source, but it shows, that Text's representation can be changed, though there weren't any examples.

Comment: @Variatus Preferably data should be saved as it is, but without other solutions this condition can be omitted. I already did the same with formula, but it leaves me with adding another column.

Comment: Technically, you can change what text looks like using numberformatting. However, you would need VBA and would need to have a separate format for each entry containing a slash.  I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of accomplishing what you want using `NumberFormat`.  The appropriate number format is generated by VBA event code.

There is a BIG disadvantage in that you will need a different number format for every unique entry that contains a `"/"`, and the number of allowable number formats can be limiting.

However, it does not require helper columns, and does not alter the original data stored in the cell.

Anything entered in column A will be formatted according to the rules.
If a slash is present, the code will alter the numeric sections; but does not test to see that both are numeric.  So `abc/1` --> `abc01`, but you can change that if you like.

This is Worksheet code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim FormatRange As Range, C As Range
    Const Fmt As String = "000000;000000;000000;@"
    Dim V As Variant

Set FormatRange = Range("A:A")
If Not Intersect(Target, FormatRange) Is Nothing Then
    For Each C In Intersect(Target, FormatRange)
        If InStr(C.Text, "/") = 0 Then
            C.NumberFormat = Fmt
        Else
            V = Split(C.Text, "/")
            V(0) = Format(V(0), "000000")
            V(1) = Format(V(1), "00")
            C.NumberFormat = ";;;" & Chr(34) & Join(V, "") & Chr(34)
        End If
    Next C
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sad it can't be done without macro though it looks like something I need. Forgot I could actualy separate string in two parts and join them, thanks a lot, I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: No need to check if parts of string are numeric, these are 100% numeric every time, forgot to mention.

Comment: @AntiDrondert That makes the code simpler.  The major caveat with this method is that a workbook is limited to having 64,000 unique cell formats/cell styles.  Replacing the value with the "format" would be more robust, but would preclude keeping the original data without a helper column.

Comment: The main problem is that I can't alter table at all. As for values, I'm pretty sure someone else might need original data in future.