# How to make a mask in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a text type column in excel with these values

```
2/02/1472
22/88/1234
1/8/1234
22/88/12
01/01/222
88/2222
```

I want to set a mask that my values do look like this

```
02/02/1472
22/88/1234
01/08/1234
22/88/1200
01/01/2220
00/88/2222
```

My mask is 00/00/0000 (if a part does not exist, fill with zero)

I use this `"=text(A1,"00/00/0000")"` but have error

Comment: I think you'll need to create a custom format first, or use other formulas to make it. Because on the first and second ##/ if there is just one digit a zero is added to the left and if it is /#### less than 4 digits, zeros are added to the right. With this info you can make some formula logic to make it.

Comment: The problem you've got is you're trying to do a number format on text

Comment: You would need some VBA code to do that.

Comment: What would be result for 18? `00/18/0000` or `18/00/0000` or `00/00/0018`?

Comment: By this logic, `01/01/222` should be `01/01/0222`, no? Or this is the point of it?

Comment: Check this [Excel Custom format Check for character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051456/excel-custom-format-check-for-character), might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you also mention `vba` in your tags, here is a User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit
Function FormatMask(S As String) As String
    Dim V
    Dim I As Long
    
V = Split(S, "/")
            
V(UBound(V)) = Format(V(UBound(V)), "0000")

For I = UBound(V) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    V(I) = Format(V(I), "00")
Next I

FormatMask = Right("00/00/" & Join(V, "/"), 10)

End Function
```

[image]

## EDIT

@pnuts pointed out that your examples show that the first two groups are left-padded with 0's, but the third group is right-padded with zero's.

The following modification accomplishes that:

```
Option Explicit
Function FormatMask(S As String) As String
    Dim V
    Dim I As Long

V = Split(S, "/")

'This pads with 0's on the left
'V(UBound(V)) = Format(V(UBound(V)), "0000")

'For padding on right as you show for the last group only:
V(UBound(V)) = Left(V(UBound(V)) & "0000", 4)

For I = UBound(V) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    V(I) = Format(V(I), "00")
Next I

FormatMask = Right("00/00/" & Join(V, "/"), 10)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is oddly familiar.. :D

Comment: What's the point of the `Right("00/00/"` in the final line in this?

Comment: @Tom In case there are fewer than three groups.

Comment: @pnuts Yeah I think it's gone round the room ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another example why spreadsheet software is not well suited to text processing, but Excel can manage with a (horrible) formula:

```
=IF(LEN(IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))=1,"00/"&A1,IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3))="/",A1&"00",IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4))="/",A1&"0",IF(MID(A1,2,1)="/","0"&A1,A1)))))=10,IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))=1,"00/"&A1,IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3))="/",A1&"00",IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4))="/",A1&"0",IF(MID(A1,2,1)="/","0"&A1,A1)))),SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))=1,"00/"&A1,IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3))="/",A1&"00",IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4))="/",A1&"0",IF(MID(A1,2,1)="/","0"&A1,A1)))),"/","/0",1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another horrible formula for you (I've broken it down so I'm using a few helper columns which you can hide so visually it looks the same). Part of the horribleness is also due to your source data not having a consistent format

In Column `A` I've got your original list which is stored as text (Excel won't recognise these as a date or number)
In Column `B` to get the first part I have the formula

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=2, VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1)),0)
```

In Column `C` to get the middle bit I have

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))),FIND("/",RIGHT(A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))))-1)
```

and then in Column `D` I get the last bit using:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "/", ""))=2,FIND("/",A2)+1,1)))
```

I then put it all together in Column `E` and format it using

```
=TEXT(B2,"00")&"/"&TEXT(C2, "00") &"/"&TEXT(D2,"0")&REPT(0,4-LEN(D2))
```

To get your output

[image: Final Results]

You could of course combine this all into one formula, I've just broken it down for a little bit of clearness (although is still pretty bleak):

```
=TEXT(IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=2, VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1)),0),"00")&"/"&TEXT(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))),FIND("/",RIGHT(A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2),LEN(A2))))-1), "00") &"/"&TEXT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "/", ""))=2,FIND("/",A2)+1,1))),"0")&REPT(0,4-LEN(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2,IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "/", ""))=2,FIND("/",A2)+1,1)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter version:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))=1,"00",TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1),"00"))&"/"&TEXT(IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,LOOKUP(99^99,FIND("/",A2,ROW($1:$20)))-FIND("/",A2)-1),TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1),"00")),"00")&"/"&LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-LOOKUP(99^99,FIND("/",A2,ROW($1:$20))))*10000,4)
```

The only thing that you want to know is this:

`LOOKUP(99^99,FIND("/",A2,ROW($1:$20)))`

This is the function to find the last occurrence of `/`.  I assume the maximum length of the string is 20 so you can replace that if needed.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for catching that.  I will fix and update the answer shortly.

Comment: Just revised my answer to fix trailing zeros.